# Is there a standard naming convention for set variables?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Is there a standard naming convention for variables that resemble sets? Because I want to name my variables so that reading becomes as easy and intuitive as possible.

#### Details

Currently, I'm overlining letters: I have $\mathit{S} \in M$ and $\mathbb{T} \in N$ ($M$ and $N$ are completely different sets, having nothing to do with each other) throughout my thesis, so I find it intuitive (and think I have seen it elsewhere) to use $\overline{\mathit{S}} \in 2^M, \overline{\mathbb{T}} \in 2^N$ and then $\mathit{S} \in \overline{\mathit{S}}$.

That way, I have a strong connection between $\mathit{S}$ and $\overline{\mathit{S}}$ and can use this notation for all kind of symbols (e.g. $\mathit{S}$ as well as $\mathbb{T}$).

I like this since it is consistent. But if I'm using both $\mathit{S}$ and $\overline{\mathit{S}}$ in one definition/lemma/..., I find it unintuitive because I tend to think that $\overline{\mathit{S}}$ is the value of $\mathit{S}$ under some function.

So: Is my use of $\overline$ standard notation? Do you know of another standard? or more intuitive notation?

#### Update

Since $\overline$ has so many meanings already, what do you think about the following?

- $\ddot{\mathit{S}}$, or
- $\overbrace{\mathit{S}}$ (which looks less strange via pdflatex), or
- $_{2}\!\mathit{S}$

Comment: I don't  fully understand what you mean by that. Can you give more context? What field is your thesis in? In either case, overlining is **bad** and it is way way overly used in mathematics. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Its theoretical computer science: model checking and automata theory.

Comment: Why is overlining bad? Being way way overly used sounds kind of good, since I try to follow standards (as long as they make sense)...

Comment: I tend to use small letters for items, big letters for sets, \mathcal for sets of sets and \mathfrak for sets of sets of sets (e.g. $a\in A\in\mathcal{A}\in\mathfrak{A}$).

Comment: Because if I write $\overline A$ then one person would think this is the complement of $A$, another would think its the closure of $A$, and another may think it's a whole other thing.

Comment: It is overused for completely different meanings.

Comment: You have a good point there, Asaf. Complement makes no sense, but some might think of it as the closure :(

Comment: @Ido, that's what I was afraid of: having to use $a \in A \in \mathbb{A}$ or the like, because then I have to break some other naming conventions. So good point, but do you know of an alternative that is also used frequently?

Comment: Actually, I had course about automata theory and overline was used to denote complement. Another common approach is to use different sequences of the alphabet for different meanings. For example, $A,B,C$ for sets and $X,Y,Z$ for sets of sets.

Comment: @Asaf: To avoid (closure) confusion, I think I'll change from $\overline{X}$ to $\widehat{X}$ for a subset of the type that $X$ is of. Any comments on that notation?

Comment: @Ido: you are right, A,B,C for one type and X, Y, Z for another is the standard. But I want to make the connection (e.g. between $X$ and $\widehat{X}$ as clear as possible, and need this connection for various symbols ($\mathit{S}, \mathbb{T}, \dots$).

Comment: The fact that you are using $S$ and $\mathbb{T}$ for a member of a set is already - I think - not a very good notation. Why not $S$ and $T$? Perhaps you may want give us some information on what $S$ and $\mathbb{T}$ are as mathematical objects. Are they real numbers, etc?

Comment: The convention for real numbers may be as follows: $x=1$, $x\in X = \{1,2,3\}$, $X\in\mathcal{X} = \{\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\}\}$, $\mathcal{X}\in\mathfrak{X} = \cdots$.

Comment: @LordSoth: $\mathit{S}$ and $\mathbb{T}$ are two completely different objects of completely different types (so they are not elements of the same set). That's why I'm happy about having completely different symbols.

Comment: Since you've asked: $\mathit{S}$ is a specification, which is an arbitrary automaton. $\mathbb{T}$ is a test case, which is a tree in my case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My advice to you is to get your advice from your advisor. I presume that you have one, if you are writing a thesis. It is best to stick to the conventions others have set (unless they are particularly terrible). Surely your thesis cites papers, and builds on others' work. See how they denote the variables that you are after and use that convention without worrying too much.

The general convention I am familiar with is that objects get small letters ($x,y,m,n,k$), sets get capital letters ($A,B,C,X,Y$), sets of sets get calligraphic letters ($\cal U,F,M,N$), and sets of sets of sets get cursive letters ($\scr G,F,M,P$). Special sets get denoted by blackboard bold ($\Bbb{R, N, Q}$ and when context demands it, $\Bbb P$ for example).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using $M$ as a type (i.e. writing $S \in M$ to tell us what type of object $S$ is), then any subset of $M$ is also a type. So, it would not be unreasonable to write variables denoting subsets of $M$ in the same style as $M$. If necessary, you could make a conventional choice of letter for subset variables, so that they can be easily recognized.